# How can I extract the last path of an URL in Google Data Studio custom fields?

Tags: google-analytics, regex-negation, regular-language, looker-studio

I'm using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to get the last path of the `Page` Dimension in Google Data Studio. The Page URL has one identifier which is the same on all possible URLs:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                         Page                         |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| /ABC/something1/something2/something3/lastpath       |
| /ABC/something1/something2/something3/last path      |
| /ABC/something1/something2/something3/last-path      |
| /ABC/something1/something2/something3/last last-path |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I want to extract the last path behind `/something3/`, all the values in the last directory.

Here is what I got:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'/ABC/([^/]+/){3}')
```

But this matches only the `/something3/` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is to use **capturing** groups only for something you want extract. For everything else use the **non-capturing** `(?:REGEX)`.

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(
    '/ABC/something1/something2/something3/last last-path',
    '/ABC/(?:[^/]+/){3}(.+)');
```

Comment: I think this will only work when there are exactly 3 'somethings'.

Comment: Ghramotei's, is good if, you need it to happen 3 sections after /ABC/.  However, if you want it to happen for all 5th sections then: '^(?:[^\\/]*[\\/]){5}([^\\/]*)'.

Answer (score 2):

To capture "*all the values in the last directory*" (all characters after the last `/`), the following [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) does the trick:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, "([^/]*)$")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e40dbbae-9c87-4899-b23d-a56ac9810f96) as well as a GIF to elaborate:

[image]